# Как найти в одной таблице значение, а потом сравнить его с другим значением запроса?

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне нужно чтоб при выборке с одной таблицы LIMIT 1, сравнило с другим результатом и к примеру выдало true или false. Если можно простой пример
Один запрос с другим кто больше если один больше другова то  true и наоборот false.
В каждом запросе выходит одна строка с одной колонкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE f(id INT auto_increment primary key, num INT);

INSERT INTO f 
    (num)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (1),
    (2);

SELECT
    f1.num, f2.num, if(f1.num > f2.num, 'true', 'false') as answer
FROM
    f as f2,
    f as f1
WHERE
    f1.id != f2.id
LIMIT 1;
```

Сравнивает первый элемент со вторым. 
Вывод:

> 1, 2, false